# Creating a Context Menu with React-Redux

Tags: javascript, redux, contextmenu, react-redux

We use Redux in large parts of our React application. One area where we struggle with is the context menu. Up to now it worked like this:

```
onRightClick -> createItems -> openMenu -> onItemClick: invoke callback and close menu
```

So we had a callback in each item when it is clicked. With Redux, that no longer works, because:

```
dispatch(actionCreator_openContextMenu(items))
```

... performs a store update. The Redux action returned by the action creator **cannot have callbacks** in it, because they are not serializable/jsonizable.

We furthermore need to perform asynchronous operations (i.e. server roundtrips) in many context menu click actions, so the click actions are not plain store updates.

**The question is: how does this align with the Redux pattern and its constraints? How would one do this with Redux?**

To clarify: this question is **not** about the UI side in react, it's about redux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually wrote an article that covers this exact question: [Creating Reusable Generic Modals in React and Redux](https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/creating-reusable-generic-modals-react-and-redux).  The approach I described in that article can be summarized as having the code that requests the dialog include a pre-made action object that gets passed to the dialog component as a prop, and the dialog can then dispatch that action (possibly with additional info attached) when it's closed.

A couple other options:

- Have the dialog dispatch some "signal" action when it closes, and use sagas or observables to execute the additional async logic in response
- There's an interesting-looking library called [redux-promising-modals](https://github.com/AKolodeev/redux-promising-modals).  I haven't used it yet myself, but it appears to have a prebuilt middleware and reducer for tracking a lost of open modals.  The middleware returns a promise whenever you dispatch `PUSH_MODAL_WINDOW`, and will resolve the promise when you dispatch the corresponding `POP_MODAL_WINDOW`.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Our internal discussion was similar. "Just include an action to call on close" - "But we need an async action creator there!" - "Then use Redux Saga!" ... and I was like "What? Shooting birds with cannonballs? Come on, there has to be a simpler way to do this."   Apparently I was wrong. Redux does have its dark sides I suppose. Still, thanks for the comprehensive answer.

Comment: For what it's worth, you _can_ include functions in action objects, and Redux itself will work - it's primarily time-travel debugging that may have issues.  See http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/Actions.html#actions-string-constants and http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/05/idiomatic-redux-tao-of-redux-part-1/ for more information.  And Redux-Saga _is_ meant for this use case of distributed/async behavior based on dispatched actions.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a redux middleware that could handle async side effects. There are dozens of libraries out there that can help with this, but I would suggest your team looks into some of the following libraries that have great communities and are well documented:

- Redux-Saga https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga (easy to understand and test)
- Redux-Thunk https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk (extremely easy to understand, hard to test)
- Redux-Observable https://redux-observable.js.org/ (you would need some previous knowledge on reactive programming, easier to test than redux-thunk)